# Calculating $\lim_{x \rightarrow α}\frac{1 - \cos(ax^2+bx+c)}{(x-α)^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits

If $α$ and $β$ are the roots of equation

$$ax^2+bx+c = 0,$$

then find the following limit

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow α}\frac{1 - \cos(ax^2+bx+c)}{(x-α)^2}.$$

Comment: What have you tried? Just asking people to do (what appears to be homework) for you isn't likely to get you any answers. And if you do, you won't learn much from them.

Comment: @Kahen thank you very much for aditing

Comment: No idea Kahen. Just trying

Comment: Try substituting $t=x-\alpha$. Calculating limits when the variable tends to 0 is usually easier.

Comment: I m feeling very very bad by getting negative voting.what was wrong in this question?

Comment: @kalpeshmpopat: You are not posting your effort, and your attitude isn't so smooth like many people tell.

Comment: I dont know that idea i got after posting the question

Comment: If you show some work or where you are getting stuck, you might get more upvotes.

Comment: @kalpeshmpopat: you always have my upvote.(+1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hints*:
1) Note that $ax^2+bx+c=a(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$
2) As I wrote in my comment, substitute $t=x-\alpha$.
3) $$\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{1-\cos z}{z^2}=\frac12$$ which $z$ should you choose?
**Edit**: Here is the complete solution
$$\lim_{x\to\alpha}\frac{1 - \cos(ax^2+bx+c)}{(x-\alpha)^2}=\lim_{x\to\alpha}\frac{1 - \cos(a(x-\alpha)(x-\beta))}{(x-\alpha)^2}=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{1 - \cos(at(t+\alpha-\beta))}{t^2}$$
Denote $\gamma=\beta-\alpha$
$$\begin{align*}L&=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{1 - \cos(at(t-\gamma))}{t^2}\frac{a^2(t-\gamma)^2}{a^2(t-\gamma)^2}=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{1 - \cos(at(t-\gamma))}{(at(t-\gamma))^2}\lim_{t\to0}a^2(t-\gamma)^2\\
&=\lim_{z\to0}\frac{1 - \cos z}{z^2}\lim_{t\to0}a^2(t-\gamma)^2=\frac{a^2(\beta-\alpha)^2}{2}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: I m not getting what you saying

Comment: Just do step 2. Now you should see how step 3 is relevant

Comment: @kalpeshmpopat: I edited my answer into a complete solution.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** There are two cases, $\alpha\ne \beta$ and $\alpha=\beta$. We can use L'Hospital's Rule twice, or expand the cosine in a power series around $x=\alpha$.

Alternately, we can use various trigonometric identities. For example, one could use the fact that $1-\cos 2t=2\sin^2 t$. That way, we only need to use L'Hospital's Rule once.

It may be useful to note that $ax^2+bx+c=a(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$.

Comment: I think $$1 -cos2t = 2sin^2t$$

Comment: can i write $$1 - cos(ax^2+bx+c) = 2sin^2((x - α)(x - β))/2)?$$

Comment: @kalpeshmpopat: Yes, thank you. I had first thought of writing $1-\cos t=2\cos^2(t/2)$, thought the more familiar $2t$ would be better, but didn't change the right-hand side. Anyway, the point of that hint is that you only need the limit of $(\sin t)/(x-\alpha)$.

Comment: Not quite. As I point out in the answer, $ax^2+bx+c=a(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$, so in your "can i write" you are missing an $a$ in front of the $(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: 1) Since you know the roots of the equation there maybe is a different way to write the equation (factorisation).

2) For the limit: Try [L'Hôpital](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)

Answer (score 0):

$\frac12(\alpha-\beta)^2$

Start by  putting $t=x-\alpha$, and then solve.

Comment: Care to elaborate a little?